# Ways of initializing the RAG graph from Scikits-Image

Tags: python, networkx, scikit-image

I would like to initialize the RAG graph object from scikit-Image with my own data in order to use it's good support for visualization.

What data do I need to perform such an initialization? What function should I call to perform such an initialization?

Answer (score 4):

The only way to initialize a graph from am image right now is the [rag_mean_color](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.future.graph.html#skimage.future.graph.rag_mean_color) function. It's input in an image and its labelled array.

The labelled array can be obtained from any segmentation algorithm such as the ones implemented in the **segmentation** module.

Here's a quick example using the Quickshift method. To better visualize a RAG, you can use any of the matplotlib's colormaps.

```
from skimage import data, segmentation
from skimage.future import graph
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


img = data.chelsea()
# A colormap to draw the edge
cmap = plt.get_cmap('autumn')

# Labelled image
qs_labels = segmentation.quickshift(img, ratio=0.5)

# Image with boundaries marked
qs_marked = segmentation.mark_boundaries(img, qs_labels,color=(0,0,0))

# Constructing the RAG
qs_graph = graph.rag_mean_color(img, qs_labels)

#Drawing the RAG
qs_out = graph.draw_rag(qs_labels, qs_graph , qs_marked, colormap=cmap)

plt.imshow(qs_out)
plt.show()
```

You can also look at the more elaborate [RAG Drawing Example](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/doc/examples/plot_rag_draw.py)

Thanks

Comment: Also see [segmentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html) module and [colormaps](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html). SO currently does not allow me to post with more than 2 links